# Java: How to execute preparedStatement in jdbc with multiple parameters in sql query?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

This is what I want to do:

```
PreparedStatement query2 = 
conn.prepareStatement ("UPDATE report SET Name = ? WHERE Id = ?");

String blah = "Jane";
int id = 1;

query2.setString(1, blah);
query2.setInt(2, id);
query2.executeQuery();
```

But I'm getting this error:

> The statement did not return a result set.

I am new to the whole jdbc world. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [executeUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29).

*"Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as an SQL DDL statement."*